# Checking number of seats available in PHP

Tags: php, session

This is the seat booking form for a cinema's website that I need to check the number of seats available when users select their seats.

There are 3 seat types (S, F, B) with the capacity of 40, 12, 13 respectively.

In HTML I have:

```
<input name="Stype" type="number" value="" max="<?php echo /the number of available seats/?>" min="0" />
<input name="Ftype" type="number" value="" max="<?php echo /the number of available seats/?>" min="0" />
<input name="Btype" type="number" value="" max="<?php echo /the number of available seats/?>" min="0" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

Then I use php to get user inputs like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$SSeats = '';
$FSeats = '';
$BSeats = '';

if(isset($POST['submit']))
{
    //get inputs by method POST
    //pass input data to the next shopping-cart page via SESSION
    $_SESSION['SSeats'] = $SSeats;
    $_SESSION['FSeats'] = $FSeats;
    $_SESSION['BSeats'] = $BSeats;
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['SAvai'] = 40 - $_SESSION['SSeats'];
    $_SESSION['FAvai'] = 12 - $_SESSION['FSeats'];
    $_SESSION['BAvai'] = 13 - $_SESSION['BSeats'];

    //Then I write above SESSIONs into a file, then output the number of
    //seats available to the HTML code
}
?>
```

Before I test this code, I did tested many things else and the SESSIONs already have values in it, so the code can run well. But when I reopen the website and go to this page, it throws an exception that the indexes 'SSeats', 'FSeats', 'BSeats' are undefined.

The requirement also includes after users view their booking cart, they can add/remove seats in the reservation.

So could somebody suggest me the way to fix it or how to make it easier.

Comment: It's okay now, I have found the solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You have two errors:

Change `$POST` to `$_POST`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

And you need `$_POST['html_element_name']` to get the value

```
    $_SESSION['SSeats'] = $_POST['SSeats'];
    $_SESSION['FSeats'] = $_POST['FSeats'];
    $_SESSION['BSeats'] = $_POST['BSeats'];
```

The code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //get inputs by method POST
    //pass input data to the next shopping-cart page via SESSION
    $_SESSION['SSeats'] = $_POST['SSeats'];
    $_SESSION['FSeats'] = $_POST['FSeats'];
    $_SESSION['BSeats'] = $_POST['BSeats'];
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['SAvai'] = 40 - $_SESSION['SSeats'];
    $_SESSION['FAvai'] = 12 - $_SESSION['FSeats'];
    $_SESSION['BAvai'] = 13 - $_SESSION['BSeats'];

    //Then I write above SESSIONs into a file, then output the number of
    //seats available to the HTML code
}
?>
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- I writing now, and greetings to you, I back ;-)

Comment: I noticed the explanation edit, which is why I deleted it, cheers

Comment: Yes I do write $_POST in my code, and the variables $SSeats, $FSeats, $BSeats are holding POST values in the form

Comment: @JayNg. and what is the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the `if(isset)`. `$_POST` is missing an underscore, as well as you were not calling the `$_POST` variables when defining the session variables. You were calling blank variables.

```
<?php
session_start();
$SSeats = '';
$FSeats = '';
$BSeats = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) //typo fixed here
{
    //get inputs by method POST
    //pass input data to the next shopping-cart page via SESSION
    $_SESSION['SSeats'] = $_POST['SSeats'];
    $_SESSION['FSeats'] = $_POST['FSeats'];
    $_SESSION['BSeats'] = $_POST['BSeats'];
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['SAvai'] = 40 - $_SESSION['SSeats'];
    $_SESSION['FAvai'] = 12 - $_SESSION['FSeats'];
    $_SESSION['BAvai'] = 13 - $_SESSION['BSeats'];

    //Then I write above SESSIONs into a file, then output the number of
    //seats available to the HTML code
}
?>
```